# Is there a way to apply restrictions on custom list columns based off the users access role?

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, 2016, custom-list, access

I have a SharePoint custom list in a similar format to below:

ID, Raised by, Raised by, Bulk Upload Type, Date of request, Additional Contacts (for updating), Status

I would like the 'Status' field to be read-only unless the user is in the 'Site Owners' access role for the page - is there a way of doing this on SharePoint 2016?

Comment: If you want to make Status field in list form as a read only then you can do it using custom solutions. But, in general you can add column level permissions. Users can still make changes to status field from grid/datasheet view.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not support column-level security. While you can implement solutions to hide the column, the data is ultimately accessible.

One thing you could think about is abstracting away the data access and permission. For example, build a Power App that accesses the data with a defined account.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with trevor; column-level permission is not supported in SharePoint. In addition, you could go to [this forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Community/ct-p/PowerApps1#) which is dedicated to PowerApps for more help if you need it in the future.